# NoNodesAvailableException in StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php : No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I use elasticsearch v 5.5.2 with laravel 5.3 - scout v -2.0.

I a trying to executing below code but I am getting this error. NoNodesAvailableException.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
use Elastica\Client as ElasticaClient;

class clientController extends Controller
{
    protected $elasticsearch;
    protected $elastica;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->elasticsearch = ClientBuilder::create()
                //->setConnectionPool('\Elasticsearch\ConnectionPool\SniffingConnectionPool', [])
                ->build();
        $elasticConfig=['host'=>"locahost",
            "port"=>9200,
            "index"=>'pets'];
        $this->elastica = new  ElasticaClient($elasticConfig);
    }
    public function elasticsearchTest(){

        $param = [
            'index' => 'pets',
            'type' => 'dog',
            'id'=>'1'
        ];
        $res = $this->elasticsearch->get($param);
        dump($res); 
    }
}
```

Error

> NoNodesAvailableException in StaticNoPingConnectionPool.php line 51:
>   No alive nodes found in your cluster

It's working fine in sense. 
Result:

```
{
   "_index": "pets",
   "_type": "dog",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "name": "tommy",
      "age": "3",
      "color": "black",
      "gender": "male"
   }
}
```

Also working on http://localhost:9200/pets/dog/1.
Result:

```
{"_index":"pets","_type":"dog","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{
    "name":"tommy",
    "age":"3",
    "color":"black",
    "gender":"male"
}
}
```

Comment: Did you start the service elasticsearch ?

Comment: Elasticsearch service is already started.